# FFMPEG: SDP to HLS cur_dts is invalid

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, webrtc

I am trying to convert an RTP stream (opus, vp8) to HLS (aac,libx264) but it fails. I can easily save the stream as WebM but I can not save it as HLS and the only noticeable error is `cur_dts is invalid`. but the fact that it is convertible to WebM could mean that there must be a way to convert it to HLS.

It seems it is related to timestamps of video which are out of order. but none of the flags `genpts` `igndts` or `discardcorrupt` helped me. I also tried `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1`

```
ffmpeg 
-loglevel debug
-protocol_whitelist pipe,udp,rtp 
-f sdp 
-fflags genpts,
-analyzeduration 10000000,
-probesize 10000000',
-i pipe:0 
-y -c:v libx264 -crf 25 
-vprofile baseline 
-r 24 -g 24 
-c:a aac 
-hls_list_size 1 
-hls_time 2 
-hls_playlist_type event 
-hls_flags independent_segments 
-sc_threshold 0 
-preset veryfast 
b3a7f37f-972e-4784-8bf7-eaaad258d3c8.m3u8
```

The output:

```
Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame= 124 QP=16.26 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:8   I:6    P:12   SKIP:3582 size=75 bytes
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:      Last message repeated 1 times
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame= 125 QP=13.45 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:10  I:8    P:6    SKIP:3586 size=55 bytes
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:      Last message repeated 3 times
0|app  |  Stderr output:  *** dropping frame 140 from stream 0 at ts 138
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame= 126 QP=15.22 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:12  I:7    P:6    SKIP:3587 size=59 bytes
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:      Last message repeated 1 times
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame= 127 QP=14.70 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:14  I:8    P:7    SKIP:3585 size=65 bytes
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:      Last message repeated 1 times
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame= 128 QP=15.12 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:16  I:4    P:9    SKIP:3587 size=61 bytes
0|app  |  Stderr output:  Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0.
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame I:6     Avg QP:10.60  size:  3053
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] frame P:123   Avg QP:15.13  size:    88
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:99.4%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 0.2% 3.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.4% 0.0%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] i16 v,h,dc,p: 98%  0%  2%  0%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  0%  0% 100%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] i8c dc,h,v,p: 98%  1%  1%  0%
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [libx264 @ 0x6d01540] kb/s:43.38
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [AVIOContext @ 0x6c58ac0] Statistics: 210 bytes read, 0 seeks
0|app  |  Stderr output:  Conversion failed!
```

I also tried -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 and the output changes to this:

```
[hls @ 0x7021680] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10029056 > 10000000: forcing output
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [hls @ 0x7021680] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10026800 > 10000000: forcing output
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [hls @ 0x7021680] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10027288 > 10000000: forcing output
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [hls @ 0x7021680] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10033722 > 10000000: forcing output
0|app  |  Stderr output:  [hls @ 0x7021680] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10005822 > 10000000: forcing output
0|app  |  Stderr output:  cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
0|app  |  Stderr output:      Last message repeated 1 times
```